# How do I override django.contrib.comments field widgets?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-comments, django-widget

I'm not looking to add inline styles to the comment field in my comment form. I'm looking for a way to add the placeholder attribute to my field. What's the proper way to do this?

I was searching for a way to add/modify the widgets for the get_comment_create_data method.

This is how my current form looks:

```
# forms.py
...
class PostComment(CommentForm):
    """
    A lighter comment form.
    """
    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        """
        This needs to be overwritten to remove the fields from the class
        """
        return dict(
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_object),
            object_pk    = force_unicode(self.target_object._get_pk_val()),
            comment      = self.cleaned_data['comment'],
            submit_date  = datetime.datetime.now(),
            site_id      = settings.SITE_ID,
            is_public    = True,
            is_removed   = False,
        )
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a class method like this:

```
class PostComment(CommentForm):
    def get_comment_create_date(self):
        data = super(PostComment, self).get_comment_create_data()
        data.update(dict(
            placeholder  = 'foo'
        ))
        return data
```